# Case statement is not working on query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on jasper report.I have a table named `user` I have 2 parameters `internal`,`external` .When I use internal then my query needs to show the users where `username LIKE  '%_@__%.__%'` and when I use external then my query needs to show  the users where `username NOT LIKE  '%_@__%.__%'`.Like when `internal` then report will show 2,3,4,5 no row and when `external` then report will show only one row..My query is

```
SELECT case
when $P{internal} = 'internal' then

 id end as cid,
designation,division_name,pin_no,username FROM application_user where username      LIKE
 '%_@__%.__%'

else 
 id end as cid,
 designation,division_name,pin_no,username FROM application_user where    username NOT LIKE
   '%_@__%.__%'
```

but it is not working 
[image]

Please let me know If i'm not clear

Comment: The SQL you posted is not valid: you have an `ELSE` without a parent `WHEN` or `IF`. The `CASE WHEN` statement on line 1 is terminated by the `END` on line 4.

Comment: then how should i write

Comment: Please post data as text, not as image.

Comment: ok ...i will maintain it from nowon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projection statements cannot be parameterised in SQL directly (but you can in Dynamic SQL, obviously).

Your test expression should be evaluated in the `WHERE` block, not `SELECT`. The SQL you posted is not valid and won't run, so I'm curious how you're getting the results you're seeing.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    id AS cid,
    designation,
    division_name,
    pin_no,
    username
FROM
    application_user
WHERE
    ( $P{internal}  = 'internal' AND username     LIKE '%_@__%.__%' )
    OR
    ( $P{internal} <> 'internal' AND username NOT LIKE '%_@__%.__%' )
```

Note that this will not necessarily result in the best runtime execution plan because of the different effective query "shape" depending on the parameter value. Ideally you should have two different queries selected by your application code which have the different `username` predicates.

Comment: Actually, because the `like` has all those wildcards, it would be hard to prevent this query from doing a full-table scan.  So, performance isn't a big issue.